# Cordova on Windows Phone 8.1 injecting css script to index.html on the run

Tags: html, css, angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to inject css file url from my angular controller to my index.html:

```
<html ng-cloak ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<head>
...
        <link ng-href={{css}} rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" css-load css="css">
...
</head>
            ...
<html>
```

As my page loads I can see in the DOM Explorer that my css url injected correctly to the ng-href attribute, but no css changes occurred on the page.
I am sure that the url is correct, since - if I add the url explicitly to  the link ng-ref I can see the changes on the layout.

The problem is, that I need to reference for each user a personal css as they log in, so I cannot know in advance what url I need to use.

This css injection works fine on Android and Ios though...